# Should moderators be wiki-izing users questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, community-wiki, moderators

I noticed that this [question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/468/dos-and-donts-for-an-effective-bedtime-ritual/496#496) was changed to "community-wiki" mode, not by the original poster, but by a moderator.

Since wiki-izing a post means the poster won't gain any more reputation ... is it appropriate for moderators to take this action?  If the answer is yes, when is it *not* appropriate?

Answer (score 10):

The *community wiki* option is not available to the question author, so it *HAS* to be done by a moderator.

And the user asked *explicitly* that their question be made Community Wiki:

> This is not a question that has a single correct answer, so it should be a community wiki.

… which was entirely an appropriate application for community wiki, even if they *hadn't* asked.

The author wasn't asking for a specific answer to a problem. The author was asking for a list of suggestions. As such, no one answer is expected to be better than any other. The "value" of the question is in the entire *list* of answers, which makes it entirely appropriate (and expected) that the list be made a community collaboration. That's what community wiki is.

Comment: Ah, I see now that they asked for it.  However, why is that option not available to authors?  Is it possible to make a question community-wiki when first asked?  Is this something that could be configured by administrators so all users could wiki-ize their own posts?

Comment: Yep, I asked for CW because I couldn't find a checkbox for it in the question. Only in the answer form. That was odd. Even odder, we gained rep for the answers until the question was changed to CW; that doesn't seem fair. A checkbox in the question would seem reasonable. I haven't looked in other meta sites yet for an explanation though.

Answer (score 6):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.

Answer (score -6):

I think this kind of action by moderators is heavy handed and should be avoided.  SE style sites like this one already have a recourse to allow trusted users (those with high reputation) to edit others posts.

It should be up the original poster whether they want to allow *any* user to modify what they've written here.

Comment: In an early site, there *are* no higher-reputation users, so it is appropriate (and expected) that moderators take a more hands-on, proactive approach to keeping the site on track while the community is still forming. As a matter of fact, we've found early moderation to be **CRUCIAL to a site's success.** I discuss this more thoroughly here: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/166/too-much-censorship-in-this-community/173#173

Comment: And your premise of *edit-by-permission-only* goes against the very nature of this site. Take a look at the FAQ, near the bottom where it says **"Other people can edit my stuff?!"** -- http://parenting.stackexchange.com/faq#editing

Comment: What concerned me was not so much that people could edit, but the knowledge that (at least it used to be the case) on most SE sites once a question is community-wiki, the poster no longer gains reputation.  I *want* users to gain reputation for their good questions, and therefore gain more power to moderate the rest of the site... I *want* the community to scale along with the site...